# What does a tensorflow "op" do?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

Below I have created a tf placeholder named "op testing":

```
self.center_words = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[self.batch_size], name='op testing')
print("Extracting the op", self.center_words.op)
```

When I print that **self.center_words.op** it prints out a structure like this:

```
op: "Placeholder"
attr {
  key: "dtype"
  value {
    type: DT_INT32
  }
}
attr {
  key: "shape"
  value {
    shape {
      dim {
        size: 128
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works for any TensorFlow variable, function output, etc. What is this ***.op***?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*TensorFlow Operations*, also known as *Ops*, are nodes that
perform computations on or with Tensor objects. After computation, they return zero or
more tensors, which can be used by other Ops later in the graph. To create an Operation,
you call its constructor in Python, which takes in whatever Tensor parameters needed for
its calculation, known as inputs, as well as any additional information needed to properly
create the Op, known as *attributes*. The Python constructor returns a handle to the
Operation’s output (zero or more Tensor objects), and it is this output which can be passed
on to other Operations or *Session.run*

Answer (score 10):

Short answer.

[Ops](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/basic_usage)  are say the core of `tensorflow`.

> TensorFlow is a programming system in which you represent computations
>   as graphs. Nodes in the graph are called ops (short for operations).
>   An op takes zero or more Tensors, performs some computation, and
>   produces zero or more Tensors.

`self.center_words.op` in your example prints out the features of  `self.center_words` in that json-like format

Comment: is this coming from core of the tensorflow ? What is a tensorflow object get rifered  to ?  Is that some kind of C++ implementation ?

Comment: This link is dead.

Answer (score 7):

Simply put, it prints the property of the particular *tensor object*. That is, it gives out details about

- which operation is responsible for the generation of the tensor
- what is its `return type`
- what is its `dimension`

and all possible information about the tensor object in question.

Minimal Example:

```
In [74]: with tf.Session() as sess:
    ...:     zer = tf.zeros(shape=(32, 32))
    ...:     print(zer.op)
    ...:     
name: "zeros_11"
op: "Const"
attr {
  key: "dtype"
  value {
    type: DT_FLOAT
  }
}
attr {
  key: "value"
  value {
    tensor {
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      tensor_shape {
        dim {
          size: 32
        }
        dim {
          size: 32
        }
      }
      float_val: 0.0
    }
  }
}
```

---

P.S.: Ignore the number(`_11`) in (`zeros_11`)  (that is in the value of the key `name`). It is just a counter to track the runs. It keeps incrementing on every run within a session.

---

Source Implementation:

Code: [tf.Tensor.op](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L273)
Docs: [tf.Tensor.op](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#op)

Comment: so  that increasing number behavior in tf objects is manipulated by training class when it's training as far as I think.

Comment: is this coming from core of the tensorflow ? What is a tensorflow object get rifered  to ?  Is that some kind of C++ implementation ?

Comment: @ShamaneSiriwardhana Added code reference. Please check it out